# JPA insert NULL Value in ReferenceColumnName

Tags: jpa

I have the following pice of code to insert and update:

```
    List<Abfragen> abfragenListe = new ArrayList<Abfragen>();
    abfrage = new Abfragen();
    abfrage.setDatum(new Date());
    abfrage.setGesuchtNach(suchfeld);
    abfragenListe.add(abfrage); 
    em.persist(abfrage);
    benutzer.setAbfragen(abfragenListe);        
    em.merge(benutzer);
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "BENUTZERID")
private List<Abfragen> abfragen;
```

My Problem is now, that if i insert a new 'Abfrage' and merge the 'benutzer' only the last insert has an id in the referencColumn of my DBMS as shown in the picture. So what is my mistake? THX

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `benutzer.setAbfragen(abfragenListe);`  call is replacing the collection of referenced Abfragen instances with only the new Abfragen.  You seem to want to add the Abfragen instance to the existing collection, not clear the collection.  Use

```
 benutzer.getAbfragen().add(abfrage);
```

instead.